# Your sweat soaking throught the floor

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does "**your sweat soaking through the floor"** mean?

Does the "sweat" there passes through the floor? Shouldn't it be "sweat soaking on the floor"?

Source: [The Greatest Showman](https://youtu.be/NxIILbNMTHY) *the lyrics is around 0.15-0.22 sec.

Comment: I would consider this expression metaphorical. To me, it suggests there is so much sweat that it has begun soaking into the floor. Also, please correct the typo 'you' for 'your' in the body of the question.

Comment: Source? Context? If there are any holes/cracks in the floor (around nails or between boards, for example), of course a liquid could go through the floor.

Comment: Please see the link above that I've just added.

Comment: After viewing the source, it still sounds to me like a poetic way of saying the cast of the show work very hard, and sweat a lot.

Comment: @RossMurray, if they are being idiomatic, that I couldn't care less, BUT they are **ungrammatical** aren't they?. It should be "your sweat soaking **to** the floor, right?

Comment: No, your sweat might fall to the floor or run onto the floor. Soaking has a different meaning. It means to *permeate*.

Comment: @John. I would accept 'dropping to the floor' or 'soaking into the floor'. 'Through' or 'into' mean the same thing. 'Through' does not necessarily mean all the way through to the other side. Also 'to' shows some sort of destination'. 'Soaking' is something that happens while a liquid remains in the same position.

Comment: The Greatest Showman is about P.T. Barnum and his travelling show, such a show used a Big Top tent, the floor of the show ring would be made of sawdust which is absorbant  to fluids. When an elephant decides to urinate you need something to soak it up.

Comment: @Sarriesfan, brilliant! That must be it. You can see the light brown floor there "sawdust" as you said, tnx